# Junit integration test

Tags: spring, junit, integration-testing

I am trying to do Integration test as below.
My autowired `MyService` has other autowired dependencies as `BCryptPasswordEncoder` which causes myService class creation fail. I don't want to inject mock version. Any idea? Thanks

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/application-component-context.xml")
public class ServiceUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() throws Exception {
        TestJNDIDB.create();
    }

    @Before
    public  void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessRegistration() throws Exception {    
        SomeObject object = myService.ProcessSomeObject;
    }

}
//this is real class and works while application run
@Component
MyService(){
    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}
```

**EDIT:** The reason I was avoiding mock in the integration test, it is because I have read that some unexpected behavior can happen during usage.

- https://dzone.com/articles/when-mockitos-injectmocks-does-not-inject-mocks
- https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/

Comment: "I don't want to inject mock version".   Why dont you want to inject a mock version?  As you stated, the real version is problematic.  Mocking is a very common approach to addressing this problem.  So why dont you want to use a mock?

Comment: @EJK, I think I want to see how far  I can go with real object instead of Mock for integration test, I will use if I don't have any other option. Also guessing I might have same kind of problem when I need to save something on the session.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. I have bean `BCryptPasswordEncoder` defined in spring-security.xml and I was loading only application-context xml.

**As a solution:**
I defined the bean also in application-context.xml and I was able to use real db and real `myService` class for integration test.